# List ID in jQuery

Tags: jquery, list

I need to extract the list IDs "first", "second", and "final". My List has:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <ul id="testnav">
        <li> <a href="#">Page</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#">Page.</a>
            <ul id="subnav">
                <li id="first"><a href="#">Value1</a></li>
                <li id="second"><a href="#">Value2</a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="navbelow">
        <li id="final"><a href="#">Next</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

My jQuery code is following and it returns an empty alert. What should I change in order to alert list id "first","second", and "final"?

```
$("#testnav a").click(function(ev){
    var a=$(this).attr('id');
    alert(a); // Not working
    ev.preventDefault();
```

});

Answer (score 1):

"this" in  your script is referring to the anchors, and not the list-items. You don't have the id's on the anchors, so you will get nothing back when requesting .attr("id");

I'd suggest using [.parent()](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/parent#expr) to access the list-items, or put your click event on the list-items instead of the anchors.

Answer (score 0):

As has been mentioned, you are referring to the anchor (A) element rather than the list element. You will need to use something like `$(this).prev('li')` instead of `$(this)`